# Informatica Data Integration - Connection issue

Tags: informatica

I have been trying to use Informatica Data Integration to transfer data from a source to destination with the ETL flow. I was planning on using the XML generated from datastage. But, when I try to establish connection to the target, none of the connections are listed. I would like to know if there's something I'm missing in case of configuration.
I have created 2 connections but none of those are listed under target[image]

Amazon S3 will be used for Source and Destination.[image]

I went through a few blogs and most of the response were related to refresh issue but I don't think that's the case

Comment: Hi - I think you need to supply more details in order for someone to help you. For example, what is the target that you want to write to? Also, what does "I was planning on using the XML generated from datastage" mean? You were planning to use this for what purpose and how? If you are using Informatica why are you also using Datastage?

Comment: So have you created a connection to your S3 bucket - what's the actual issue you are facing? From the screenshot it looks like the Connection drop-down is greyed out which suggests you haven't created any connections and therefore there are none to select from

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enIN1032IN1032&q=iics+create+connection+against+s3&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq74yaguv-AhUNF1kFHVceAxQQBSgAegQIBxAB&biw=1422&bih=677&dpr=1.35

Comment: @NickW, I have created a connection but it is just not getting listed in the target page

Comment: Have you tried using the 'New Connection" button right there on the Target tab (2nd screenshot)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well. The connections are being created but they are not getting listed in the dropdown. 
Has anyone ever faced this issue?